# MVC Helper method to handle Anonymous types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a view Helper class that can take an arbitrary list of parameters, but trying to get a simple syntax on the view side.  This is using the Razor engine in MVC.NET.  I realize I can do this by using a ViewDataDictionary, however I prefer the Anonymous type syntax.

```
@Helper.CreateDiv(new {@class="myclass", @id="myId"})
```

```
public static string DivHelper(object values) {
    string html = "&lt;div";
    //How do I iterate through the key/value pairs here?  

    //foreach(var key in values.Keys){
    //   html += String.format(" %s=\"%s\"",key,values[key];
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(obj)` to convert an anonymous type into a RouteValueDictionary.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do the same thing with `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes`, which just calls the one from WebPages.